# Delete lines that contain $, except lines with one $ at the end

Tags: text-processing

I want to delete any line containing `$` followed by a character, like:

```
a$df
aheh$b$
t$$a
```

I wish to keep lines containing **one** `$`, at the end of line:

```
abc$
abcdwh$
```

The text file contains 2M lines.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because `aheh$b$` is a line which contains one `$` at the end, so it should not be deleted according to the title. But in the body of the text that line should be kept, not deleted. So the question is not well defined.

Comment: The question is perfectly clear: the lines to be deleted: if there is atleast one inner dollar literal.

Comment: @medleto27 Welcome to UNIX stackexchange. I have rephrased your question based on your examples and hope I have made clear what you are asking. Please confirm.

Comment: @RakeshSharma Title: "Delete lines that contain $, except lines with one $ at the end"; Line: "aheh$b$". Line contains one $ at the end? **Yes**. Should line be deleted? (1) According to the title: **No**. (2) According to the samples: **Yes**. If that is perfectly clear for you, I am missing something there. If it were perfectly clear, it would not have generated all the confusion in the answers and comments.

Comment: @Quasimodo The clearest title should have been : delete all those lines that have atleast one dollar not at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` metacharacter in `sed` is matched literally via two ways:

- either we backslash it `\$` or
- enclose it in square brackets `[$]`

But there is yet another way,  if the `$` is not the last character in a regex then it is treated as a literal. So the following

```
sed -e '/$./d' file
```

is tailor made for your problem.

Comment: This answer will not delete `aheh$b$`

Comment: @thecarpy why not? it works, at least for me on GNU sed and I don't think it is some GNU specific feature

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: And that is why the sed has been invoked with `-e`.

Answer (score 2):

Delete a line if it contains `$` followed by anything (`.`):

```
sed '/\$./d' file
```

This pattern also works with `grep`:

```
grep -v '\$.' file
```

Comment: This answer will not delete `aheh$b$`.